# Good use for RTTI

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have been reading the new book [*Coding in Delphi*](http://tinyurl.com/p6fqbfq) by Nick Hodges. I just finished the chapters on RTTI and Attributes, and I am understanding some of the basics of RTTI, but I am wondering if anyone has any good examples of using RTTI and or attributes.

Comment: Have a look at the source of Spring4D. You can find it on BitBucket.

Comment: See e.g. also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898212/where-are-the-delphi-attributes-real-world-examples

Comment: Do you understand the advantages of Generics?  Generics basically let you perform the same actions on any different type.  RTTI is similar, but it goes deeper: it lets you perform the same actions on *the members of* any different type.  The classic use case is (de)serialization; that's what it was first added for: to support DFM streaming.  But there are plenty of other interesting uses as well...

Comment: Here is another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657502

Answer (score 1):

A very good starting point is [delphi.about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/delphirtti.htm). Also you can search on StackOverflow to see questions about **Delphi** and **RTTI** tags, to see on what different users from here used RTTI.